# Can you give some practical uses of socket.ntohl(x) ,.. in socket programming in python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I was learing socket programming from python docks and i reach to these things :

> socket.ntohl(x) Convert 32-bit positive integers from network to host
> byte order. On machines where the host byte order is the same as
> network byte order, this is a no-op; otherwise, it performs a 4-byte
> swap operation.
>
> socket.ntohs(x) Convert 16-bit positive integers from network to host
> byte order. On machines where the host byte order is the same as
> network byte order, this is a no-op; otherwise, it performs a 2-byte
> swap operation.
>
> Changed in version 3.10: Raises OverflowError if x does not fit in a
> 16-bit unsigned integer.
>
> socket.htonl(x) Convert 32-bit positive integers from host to network
> byte order. On machines where the host byte order is the same as
> network byte order, this is a no-op; otherwise, it performs a 4-byte
> swap operation.
>
> socket.htons(x) Convert 16-bit positive integers from host to network
> byte order. On machines where the host byte order is the same as
> network byte order, this is a no-op; otherwise, it performs a 2-byte
> swap operation.

So all i can do with these functions is just putting some integer inside parentheses and then i have the result :

```py
import  socket

a=socket.ntohs(32) #example number

print(a)
 

result : 8192
```

Can you give some examples that makes sense with those functions?

Comment: They are less useful in Python. They are probably only here because the C version of sockets has them. In the C version of sockets you have to translate your port numbers with htons

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about which machines are using big endian vs little endian.

I'm not a user of IBM mainframes but it seems: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=hosts-network-byte-order that they use big endian. IBM pcs however, use little endian.

The TCP/IP standard network byte order is big-endian so it depends on the machine where the application code will run and whether it is little or big endian. If there is a mismatch between your network and your hardware byte orders, you need to use a function like the one you indicated.

This is one example.

Comment: Pre-Intel Macs were all big-endian as well.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `int` has the same endianness as the processor it runs on.

In computer networks, while transmitting and receiving data packets, *Big Endian Ordering* is used.

Therefore, you have to convert before sending data to the network and after receiving data from the network depending on the architecture the python interpreter is running on.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness